# Mantener el color (activo) de un onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick

quiero mantener el color del onClick así como el href, que hasta que borras caché vuelve a su color original, con mi código le pico a un TD de mi tabla y este se pinta, pero una vez que salgo de la pagina se quita y tengo que volver a darle, ¿existe alguna forma?

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', '#green');
        }
        /*else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }*/
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, tendrías que usar cookies (aunque borrando el caché sucedería lo mismo) entonces una propuesta es usar bases de datos para almacenar que el usuario ha hecho clic.

Comment: ¿como lo haces con cookies @Diego ?

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a la comunidad StackOverflow.

Con respecto a tu pregunta es posible realizarlo a través de cookies (aunque estás son de forma temporal y cuando se borre el caché sucedería lo mismo que planteas)

Puedes usar las siguientes funciones:

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Y la parte que detecta el clic del usuario quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(getCookie('color') == null)
    {
        $(this).css('background', 'white');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css('background', getCookie('color'));
    }
    $('td').click(function () {
        
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', 'green');
            setCookie('color','green',30); //Establecemos la cookie por 30 días
        }
        /*else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }*/
    });
});
```

Referencias: [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Al final tu script debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(getCookie('color') == null)
    {
        $(this).css('background', 'white');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css('background', getCookie('color'));
    }
    $('td').click(function () {
        
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', 'green');
            setCookie('color','green',30); //Establecemos la cookie por 30 días
        }
        /*else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }*/
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: groso!!!, solo que no funciono diego :$ pinta pero de nuevo al cerrar y volver abrir tengo que volver a pintarlo, no he borrado cache, ¿habrá algo mas que mover y si puedes poner también con base de datos?

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, le he cambiado líneas, pero no guarda el color ‍♂️